# Registering reducer in app.module shows error in angular ngrx state management

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-reducers

I am creating an application in Angular 12 and the latest NgRx library for turorial purposes. I have the below model, action, reducer, and app state class.

**Model**

```
export interface Tutorial {
  name: string;
  url: string;
}
```

**Actions**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Tutorial } from '../_models/tutorial.model'

export const ADD_TUTORIAL       = '[TUTORIAL] Add'
export const REMOVE_TUTORIAL    = '[TUTORIAL] Remove'

export class AddTutorial implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_TUTORIAL

    constructor(public payload: Tutorial) {}
}

export class RemoveTutorial implements Action {
    readonly type = REMOVE_TUTORIAL
    
    constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export type Actions = AddTutorial | RemoveTutorial
```

**Reducer**

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { Tutorial } from '../_models/tutorial.model';
import * as TutorialActions from './../_actions/tutorial.actions'

const initialState: Tutorial = {
    name: 'Initial Tutorial',
    url: 'http://google.com'
}

export function reducer(state: Tutorial[] = [initialState], action: TutorialActions.Actions) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case TutorialActions.ADD_TUTORIAL:
            return [...state, action.payload];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**App State**

```
import { Tutorial } from "./_models/tutorial.model";

export interface AppState {
    readonly tutorial: Tutorial[];
}
```

Now I would like to import the reducer in the **app.module.ts** file. Here is the code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducer } from './_reducers/tutorial.reducer';
import { ReadComponent } from './read/read.component';
import { CreateComponent } from './create/create.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      ReadComponent,
      CreateComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      StoreModule.forRoot({ tutorial: reducer }),
      AppRoutingModule,
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

But in the **app.module.ts** file, importing reducer is causing an error. The error is shown below:

> Error: src/app/app.module.ts:19:29 - error TS2322: Type '(state:
> Tutorial[] | undefined, action: Actions) => Tutorial[]' is not
> assignable to type 'ActionReducer<Tutorial[], Action>'.   Types of
> parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
> Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'Actions'.
> Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action' but required in type 'RemoveTutorial'.
>
> 19       StoreModule.forRoot({ tutorial: reducer }),
> ~~~~~~~~
>
> src/app/_actions/tutorial.actions.ts:20:17
> 20     constructor(public payload: number) {}
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 'payload' is declared here.

[image]

As I am new in NgRx, I don't understand why the problem is happening. Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while since I used that syntax it it might be a regression bug. You can assert it to an `ActionReducerMap`

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ tutorial: reducer } as ActionReducerMap<any,any>)
```

Also, I would suggest to take a look at the createAction and createReducer syntax - it makes things simpler.